# how to send data with twisted protocol via factory

Tags: python, network-programming, twisted

I'm writing a client implementing a custom protocol, and have a factory for it. My problem is the following: my client has bi-dir communication, and sometimes I want to tell it "send this data". But all I have is the factory object:

```
class MyFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = MyProtocol

    def __init__(self, recv_callback):
        self.recv_callback = recv_callback

    def send_message(self, msg):
        self.protocol.send_message(msg)
```

So I create a factory and have a factory object, I don't the protocol object. When `send_message` above is called I get an error because `self.protocol` is just a class, not an object.

How can I do this? Should I also expose the protocol for connection in addition to the factory?

Thanks

Comment: can't you just use the constructor to make an object?

Comment: @Dhaivat Pandya: i don't understand

Comment: @Dhaivat Pandya: you don't know twisted, i see. please don't answer then

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have access to all of the objects you want.  The factory is responsible for creating protocol instances, so if you want to keep the protocol instance around where the factory can use it, override `buildProtocol` and save the instance:

```
class MyFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = MyProtocol

    ...

    def buildProtocol(self, address):
        proto = ClientFactory.buildProtocol(self, address)
        self.connectedProtocol = proto
        return proto
```

However, this approach is lacking in one important feature.  It does not make it easy to tell when `buildProtocol` has been called and `connectedProtocol` has been set.  If you try to use this attribute naively:

```
factory = MyFactory()
reactor.connectTCP(host, port, factory)
factory.connectedProtocol.send_message(...)
```

The code will fail with an `AttributeError` because the connection has not yet actually been set up.  Since Twisted is event driven, you need to make sure to use this code by responding to an event that says the connection has been set up.

You might do this by firing a callback when the protocol is constructed instead of just setting an attribute.  Twisted actually has a helper factory which does something like this already:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientCreator

cc = ClientCreator(reactor, MyProtocol)
whenConnected = cc.connectTCP(host, port)

# Or the equivalent with endpoints
#  from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
#  from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
#  endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port)
#  factory = ClientFactory()
#  factory.protocol = MyProtocol
#  whenConnected = endpoint.connect(factory)

def cbConnected(connectedProtocol):
    connectedProtocol.send_message(...)

def ebConnectError(reason):
    # Connection attempt failed, perhaps retry
    ...

whenConnected.addCallbacks(cbConnected, ebConnectError)
```

You could also save the reference to `connectedProtocol` in the `cbConnected` callback so that you can continue to use it later on.  You might also start whatever other operations want to use the connected protocol in `cbConnected`, so that they don't try to use the connection before it is actually available.

Comment: thank you, but docs say not use ClientCreator and do use endpoints instead, right?

Comment: endpoints are newer and nicer and somewhat more flexible.  I thought ClientCreator would make for an easier to understand answer. :)  I'll add an endpoints-based version.